# Explanation of 'CA1800: Do not cast unnecessarily' needed

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I'm a little bit confused about the Code Analysis warning in Visual Studio. The following code raises it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var something = new Something();
    object expression = "Any value";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                something.Help = expression as string;
                break;

            case 1:
                something.Description = expression as string;
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Something
{
    public string Help;
    public string Description;
}
```

The [documentation of CA1800](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx) says:

> ... Duplicate casts decrease performance, especially when the casts
>   are performed in compact iteration statements. For explicit duplicate
>   cast operations, store the result of the cast in a local variable and
>   use the local variable instead of the duplicate cast operations. ...

I can use and assign a local variable, yes. But the casts shown above won't be executed in one iteration. So, in my opinion, this can't be more expensive than using a local variable.

In my real method the variable `expression` can have many other types and the class `Something` properties of the other types. There's an other parameter, which replaces `i` and there's no `for-loop`.

Assume I create one local variable for any possible type of `expression`. Then many cast operations will be executed, whereas only one will be needed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var type1 = expression as Type1;
    var type2 = expression as Type2;
    var type3 = expression as Type3;
    var type4 = expression as Type4;
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            something.*** = type1;
            break;

        case 1:
            something.*** = type2;
            break;

        ...
    }
}
```

THAT is expensive...

**Can somebody tell me the background of this warning?** That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't result in that warning for me.  That said, why is `expression` typed as `object` and not `string` in the first place?

Comment: @Servy Did you enable code analysis? In my example project I choosed **Microsoft All Rules**. The provided code is a sample, which, semantically, makes no sense. So please remove the downvote....

Comment: Yes, I ran code analysis, and I didn't get that warning.  In your same, it makes perfect sense for a warning about a superfluous cast as *your sample has a superfluous cast*.  If you had a sample in which the cast was necessary in that sample, and still got a warning, then *that* would mean *something*.  That said, warnings are warnings; they have false positives.  It's why they're not errors.

Comment: That is some janky code.  Are you trying to loop through properties of an object?  Why not use reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is indicating that you're casting multiple times because of the loop.  This should resolve it:

```
var something = new Something();
object expression = "Any value";
string expressionAsString = expression as string;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            something.Help = expressionAsString;
            break;

        case 1:
            something.Description = expressionAsString;
            break;
    }
}
```

That said, as Servy mentions warnings are warnings - if your code is easier to understand with multiple casts and *it doesn't significantly affect the performance* (which can only be determined by trying it both ways and measuring the difference) then either ignore or suppress the warning.  I've seen too much code that's ugly and/or difficult to understand just to avoid a warning *that does not understand the context of the code*.

Comment: Thanks for only answering my question.